# bibliography with bib. extension

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to create a reference list however it does not work properly - for instance the second reference is now shown and the layout of the first reference do not look correct to me ?

The pictures below show the input and the output - furthermore it shows how I call the bibliography command

[[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujG5Y.png)

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Instead copy and paste it as text and mark it up as code in your question. Images are not only very inconvenient, because they don't allow for copy and paste, they also pose an accessibility issue since they can't be accessed by screen readers.

Comment: sorry my bad - i am gonna change it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following command before `\bibliographystyle{plain}` which causes all items in the bibliographic database to be added to the bibliography, even if they are not explicitly cited in the text

```
\nocite{*}
```

P.S.Try to post a minimal example instead of screenshots.

Comment: ty very much - it helped to shown the second reference - does the font of the 1st reference look properly for you ?

Comment: It looks good to me. Keep in mind, all that matters is the consistency in your document. As long all the references have the same format you are good. On top of that, once you create your .bib file, it will be very easy to change the fonts. Consider using a reference manager like Zotero https://www.zotero.org/